# Flink 1.8.2 state evolution throwing exception

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to alter a case class which has around 240 variable among which some are other pojos which are defined by me 
Example : Signal (case class) has variable PowerPojoFeature, UserFeature.
When I alter any of the pojo add new variables it throws below exception 
rg.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: The new state typeSerializer for operator state must not be incompatible.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend.getListState(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:323)

Is there any example I can write custom serialisation for this or any other solution

Answer (score 2):

Flink's serializer doesn't yet support case class evolution. You need to either use POJOs or Avro, or implement a custom serializer.

There are snippets of examples in the [documentation for custom serializers](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/custom_serialization.html).

Another approach would be to use the State Processor API to migrate the state and data type.